# Call a variable within an array

Tags: php

I currently have a variable setup in one php file:

```
<?php
$images_url = "http://foo.bar.com/helloworld/images/";
?>
```

I have a different file in which I have an array. Here's a snippet of the array:

```
'image'   => '<img src="urlencode($images_url);/news/20140528.jpg" />';
```

I'm guessing `urlencode()` is not the correct tool, but it's the most recent one I've tried.

PS. Please excuse any formatting issues, as this was composed on my phone.

Comment: `'image' => '<img src="' . urlencode($images_url) . '/news/20140528.jpg">'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following instead:

`'image'   => '<img src="' . urlencode($images_url) . '/news/20140528.jpg" />'`

Comment: Didn't quite work, but you put me on the right track.

I used `'image => '<img src="' . ($images_url) . '/news/20140528.jpg">'`

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
 'image' => '<img src="' . urlencode($images_url) . '/news/20140528.jpg" />';
```

Comment: There shouldn't be a semi-colon in an array definition